# Cannot install qwraps2

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package, qwraps2

I have tried everything I can think of to install qwraps2 but it consistently fails to install at the end of the download. Any ideas?

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 13.3.1

Matrix products: default


ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin20.2.0/11.0.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/R/arm64/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
**clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [qwraps2.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘qwraps2’**
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/qwraps2’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/4s/c7g6sqgs5zs87vzk1z86pn_80000gn/T//Rtmp4bZ0f7/filea376aa5b393/qwraps2_0.5.2.9002.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried:

- Installing the package from Github
- Installing the package manually using the .tgz file
- Installing all the dependencies first (one of them fails to install as well)
- Installing the package with (dependencies = FALSE)
- I have also updated all the packages I already have
- I have restarted R, RStudio, and my computer

Comment: Install gfortran (from https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases) and try again. If you get a different error, please edit your post to include the 'new' error